# Getting the last three elements from a List/ArrayList?

Tags: java

I need to get the last three elements added to a List. Are there any utility methods for this or will I just use a for loop that iterates down from "size(myList) - 1"?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with those elements. You need to be more specific.

Comment: @BrianRoach Well like I said, a massive amount of questions here are already answerable through docs and guides. I see tons of questions asking "is there such and such a utility method". Why don't you go and start nagging all the other users for not looking up docs and guides because you can be sure the answers to a huge amount of SO questions already exist on the net.

Comment: @sonicboom: If I can speak for myself, the number of extremely trivial questions here on SO has gotten so high, that it is difficult to find questions with actual problems. Here in your case, you have a very simple problem, you even already provide a reasonable solution yourself and probably spent more time writing the question than it should have taken you to take a quick look in the JavaDocs to check if there is a better solution.

Comment: @jarnbjo There is no solution in Java docs compared to what has been answered here by NPE below, please re-evaluate and consider keeping it open.

Answer (score 67):

You could use [`List.subList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) to get a view onto the tail of the original list:

```
List<E> tail = l.subList(Math.max(l.size() - 3, 0), l.size());
```

Here, `Math.max()` takes care of the case when `l` contains fewer than three elements.

Comment: This is good - yet belongs to a util class, anyone knows of any, if not should be easy to add.  I got it locally for now.

Comment: Nice, this actually worked.

Answer (score 5):

See:

```
List.subList(arg0, arg1)!
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `List.subList` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29

Something like

```
myList.subList(myList.size()-3, myList().size());
```

Comment: This would fail on short lists see other answer with Math.max.

Answer (score 2):

how about `subList(from, to)`?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList(int, int)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    List list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
    ListIterator i = list.listIterator(list.size());
    while (i.previousIndex() != list.size() - 4) {
        Object e = i.previous();
        System.out.print(e + " ");
    }
```

prints

```
4 3 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `java.util.Stack` is more useful here. What is the usage of your list?